# Change ClickOnce Publish Folder Location

Tags: c#, clickonce

How can I change the Publishing Folder of already deployed applications? E.G.

Currently the path is

> \\Server1\App

but I want to change this to

> \\Server2\App

For performance reasons (Server1 is becoming overloaded) and therefore I'm planning to move majority of our shared folders including the Apps folder to a different server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just change the URL and expecct it to work. The deployment provider URL is part of the identity of the deployment. If you change it by just changing it and deploying a new version, your users will have to uninstall and reinstall.